# ¿Como agrupar en horarios de 8hs? SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, script, datetime

Estoy trabajando en un script en donde tengo que mostrar los horarios cada 8hs pero a partir de las 6 de las mañana agrupados, de 6 de la mañana de un día a 6 de la mañana de otro día. Por ejemplo un registro es de las 20/02/2021 06:15:00 quiero que me muestre que es de las 20/02/2021 06:00:00, si hay un registro de 20/02/2021 08:00:00 quiero también que muestre 20/02/2021 06:00:00. Ósea, de las 06:00 a las 14:00 quiero que muestre que muestre 06:00, de las 14:01 a 22:00 que muestre 14:00, y de 22:01 a 06:00 del día siguiente que muestre las 22:00.

Tengo un script hecho que hasta las 08:00  lo hace bien, pero a partir de las 8:15 muestra las 14:00 y a partir de la 16:00 me muestra las 22:00.

El script es el siguiente:

```
declare @fragmentacion smallint = 480 --> equivale 8hs en minutos

--> 360 equivale a 6hs en minutos

select dateadd(mi, 360 -(datepart(hh,dateadd(mi,-1,trh_fecha)) * 60 +  datepart(mi,dateadd(mi,-1,trh_fecha))) % @wfragm -1,trh_fecha),
toh_fecha
from trhra
where trh_fecha between '20110601' and '20110602'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agrego consulta con explicación en comentarios.

```
create table #Registros(
    fecha DATETIME
)

insert into #Registros values('2021-02-20 06:15:00')
insert into #Registros values('2021-02-20 08:15:00')
insert into #Registros values('2021-02-20 14:15:00')



-- Crear los intervalos de cada grupo, tomando como base @FechaInicial
-- e incrementando en intervalos de 8 horas
declare @FechaInicial DATETIME = '2021-02-20 06:00:00'
declare @Intervalo1 DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, 8 , @FechaInicial)
declare @Intervalo2 DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, 16 , @FechaInicial)
declare @Intervalo3 DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, 24 , @FechaInicial)



select 
fecha FechaOriginal, 
-- Si la fecha es menor o igual que la fecha del intervalo siguiente
-- entonces pertenece al intervalo anterior
case when fecha <= @Intervalo1 then @FechaInicial
     when fecha <= @Intervalo2 then @Intervalo1
     when fecha <= @Intervalo3 then @Intervalo2
end Grupo
from 
#Registros


drop table #Registros
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pudo resolver el problema con los intervalos.